$P^{\#P}$ complete problems
Are there any known $P^{\#P}$ complete problems?
The problem would have to be at least as hard as anything in the polynomial hierarchy, but perhaps not as hard as PSPACE

For example, one such complete problem is given in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/53032 (NB $\mathrm{P^{PP}=P^{#P}}$).

@EmilJeřábek What is NB?

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NB#Phrase

I have never heard of it in my life before. I thought you were doing some type of a dot notation and had forgotten the . or something. Ok

@EmilJeřábek Isn't it actually $P^{PP}$$=$$P^{#P[1]}$ ?

No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

@EmilJeřábek I just checked the BBS86 paper and it does seem like only one call is sufficient to the D#P from a base machine. I also vaguely remember discussing it with someone many years ago... Who knows, I might be missing something. Ok.

@TayfunPay What is “BBS86”? In any case, $P^{PP}$ is closed under poly-time Turing reductions. So if $P^{PP}=P^{#P[1]}$, then $P^{PP}=P^{P^{#P[1]}}=P^{#P}$ anyway, as I was saying (but of course, it is trivial to verify this directly). So you are, in effect, claiming that both $P^{PP}=P^{#P}$ and $P^{#P}=P^{#P[1]}$.

@TayfunPay There is a [BBS86] reference in the Complexity Zoo (Balcázar, Book, Schöning, Sparse sets, lowness, and highness), but as far as I can see, it does not mention #P or PP, or indeed any class outside the polynomial hierarchy. Note also that the Zoo includes separate entries for the classes $\mathrm{P^{#P}}$ and $\mathrm{P^{#P[1]}}$ (noting that $\mathrm{P^{PP}=P^{#P}}$), so if your claim is true, it is apparently unknown to the general public.

@TayfunPay Cai and Hemachandra, Enumerative counting is hard, explicitly state $P^{#P}=P^{#P[1]}$ as an open problem right after proving various related results (non-adaptive/truth-table reductions to $#P$ oracles collapse to one call, and we have $X^{#P}=X^{#P[1]}$ [or even $X^{#P}=X^{C_=P[1]}$, I observe] for various oracle classes $X$ based on counting accepting paths of nondeteministic machines, such as UP, NP, or PP).

@TayfunPay Oh, now I know which paper you meant (same authors, different title): Balcázar, Book, Schöning, The polynomial-time hierarchy and sparse oracles. But the argument they give in Theorem A3 is just the standard trivial observation that $\mathrm{P^{PP}\subseteq P^{#P}}$ because each call to a PP oracle can be simulated by a call to a #P oracle and checking the highest-order bit of the result. It does not in any way imply or suggest that polynomially many calls to a PP oracle could be simulated by a single call to a #P oracle. So I still have no idea what you are thinking.

@EmilJeřábek ok. I do know that $P^{#P[1]} = P^{#P}$ is an open problem. I think the misinterpretation on my part arose because I just cannot conceive an instance where you would need more than one call to a #P oracle to recognize some language decided by                                                                          $P^{PP}$. After all, even $PH \subseteq P^{#P[1]}$.... In any case, it has been a while I pondered about these things. My memory is most likely distorted. Ok

Thanks, now I understand that problem there. And how this site works. I had searched for P^PP, but one has to search for "P^PP". And there is another candidate

But I could not reduce it to my problem. Perhaps it is too hard and I need something smaller than $P^{#P}$.
Are there $L^{PP}$-complete problems? Or $ALOGTIME^{PP}$-complete ones? However, it could not even compute the input for the oracle in ALOGTIME. Could you define an oracle call where the oracle gets a pointer to the original input rather than a copy of it?
